# D3 time axis - why do tick marks seem to be invisible by default?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a pretty regular graph using an X time axis.
The axis code is pretty standard:

```
var xScale = d3.time.scale()
                .domain([tlState.startdate.getTime(), tlState.enddate.getTime()])
                .range([0, width]);
            var xHourAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(xScale)
                .ticks(d3.time.hours, 6)
                .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%_Hh"))
                .tickSize(5,1)
                .orient('bottom');
            root.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'axis')
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + height + ")")
                .call(xHourAxis);
```

The `tsState.*` functions simply return starting/ending dates for the axis.
My problem: the axis tick label are visible, but I can't see the tick marks. They are clearly there in the DOM tree (`<line y2="5" x2="0"></line>`), but they only become invisible when I explicitly set their "stroke" attribute to something non-white.

I could easily solve this using CSS to set the stroke on tickmarks... But why are they invisible in the first place? I've googled around, but have found nothing indicating a default stroke color for tick marks...

Thanks a lot for any hints,
wwwald

Comment: For me, even setting `stroke` to non white still doesn't show anything :( And I can see that the tick marks are present in the DOM tree.

Comment: @Ciwan Make sure your svg's size is large enough to contain the axis. In my case, I hadn't specified the width/height attrs and my svg had defaulted to 300x150. Since my axis was translated to (0, 400), it wasn't visible even though the elements were in the DOM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [SVG spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#StrokeProperty), the default value for stroke is `none`. Since d3 uses a path for the ticks, which only show a stroke and no fill, nothing shows up until you style them.

I'm not sure why they decided on that; maybe to make adding a border to shapes a little simpler. Since stroke-width defaults to 1, adding a border only requires changing one attribute. If stroke was any other value besides `none`, stroke-width would have to default to 0 (don't want to give text a stroke by default!), and it would be a little counter intuitive to set up strokes for the first time: you'd have to know to change stroke-width to a positive number before seeing any strokes.

Why doesn't d3 fix this problem for us? d3's axis is built on top of SVGs and in general d3 lets you work very closely with the standards it is built on top of (css/html/svg). This makes it possible to push the medium to its limits, but also means you run into these issues occasionally.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, things make more sense now. 
It's strange that I didn't really find an answer online, I can hardly be the first to be confused by this... at least, I hope I'm not :-)